# On MacOS Big Sur, running Eclipse my JavaFX program hangs without starting

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, macos-big-sur

I am running a JavaFX program that ran on High Sierra
and I'm trying to run it on Big Sur, 11.2.1
I am using Eclipse for Java Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)

My class containing methods main(args) and start() extends javafx.application.Application

I have vm args:  --module-path .../javafx/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

If I set a breakpoint in main(args) and in start(), then Debug, the breakpoints are never reached.

The first 2 instructions in main() and start() print to System.err and System.out.
Nothing appears in my console window.  In my Debug window, I see the following threads, just hanging:

```
MyProgram [Java Application]
    control.MyProgram at localhost:54296
        Thread [JavaFX Application Thread] (Running)
        Daemon Thread [QuantumRenderer-0] (Running)
        Daemon Thread [InvokeLaterDispatcher] (Running)
        Daemon Thread [Thread-1] (Running)
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.macosx.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507/jre/bin/java (Feb 10, 2021, 10:32:58 PM)
```

The only thread I can suspend is the [Thread-1] thread.
When I do, it has no stack trace.
If I kill any of the other lines, the whole program quits.

My program is using JRE System Library [JavaSE-15]

How do I get my program to run?

Comment: Under "Run Configurations", in the "Arguments" tab, check that the "Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argument when launching with SWT" check box is unchecked.

Comment: Thanks, it works!  It's amazing!